# Integrate Facebook Payments with Facebook Ads API

Tags: facebook-ads-api, facebook-payments

I am creating an web app that enables users to create facebook ads. The problem is that every ad needs a budget. So I need the user to be able to set a budget and pay for it using his credit card or phone or anything else. Is it possible to do this? Do you have an example or tutorial? I have searched on google but I didn't find anything useful.

Comment: Did you get an answer? I have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

In short, no. Payment method setup isn't exposed via FB APIs. Furthermore, it depends on whether these users are using their own FB ad account through your platform or whether they're using yours.

If it's under your own ad account then you'll need to build account and payment controls yourself which is outside the scope of the FB ads platform and API.

If you let users enter their own ad account information and authorize your app to create ads on their behalf then you could just have them manually set FB payment method information as part of the onboard process for your web app.

Comment: Can you please explain more about "build payment controls yourselft which is outside FB Api?